# How do I limit some of the features of PHPMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I know that sometimes when I access shared hosting, the version of PHPMyAdmin provided has a limited number of features. Some examples:

- The "create database" input field and
  button are missing
- The number of tabs
  across the tops are limited, for
  example:
- The Privileges Tab is
  missing from the main navigation
- The
  Replication Tab is missing from the
  main navigation

I am now in the process of installing PHPMyAdmin on my VPS, I would like to limit the features which users get once they have logged in, is there a simple way to do this which I may have overlooked?

Or can anyone point me to the specific documentation which discusses this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to limit the features which users get once they have logged in, is there a simple way to do this which I may have overlooked?

I'm fairly sure phpMyAdmin adapts automatically to the privileges your mySQL user has. So if you remove the `CREATE DATABASE` privilege, the tab will vanish.

**Edit:** There are [configuration settings, too](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#ShowCreateDb), at least for the "create database" dialog: [ShowCreateDb](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#ShowCreateDb) you still need to restrict the user's privileges accordingly in any case.